# Rewrite domain extension based on parameter in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

After many tries without success I post this here. I want to rewrite the url when the following condition occurs:

> http:// www.sitename**.nl/en/**page/

Then the URL has to be rewritten to:

> http:// www.sitename**.com/en/**page/

and vice versa

> http:// www.sitename**.com/nl/**page/ -> http:// www.sitename**.nl/nl/**page/

---

**This is something that i've tried:**

*.htaccess (.nl domain)*

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename\.nl/en$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sitename.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

*.htaccess (.com domain)*

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename\.com/nl$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sitename.nl/nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

`HOST_NAME` only matches domain name from URL.

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sitename\.nl$ 
RewriteRule ^(en/.*)$ http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sitename\.com$
RewriteRule ^(nl/.*)$ http://www.sitename.nl$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```